# Multiple SVG elements with the same size display different sizes on DOM

Tags: html, css, svg

I have 2 SVG elements: (Material Design Icons)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height='24' viewBox="0 0 24 24" width='24'><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" /><path fill='#fff' d="M19 7v2.99s-1.99.01-2 0V7h-3s.01-1.99 0-2h3V2h2v3h3v2h-3zm-3 4V8h-3V5H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-8h-3zM5 19l3-4 2 3 3-4 4 5H5z" /></svg>
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height='24' viewBox="0 0 24 24" width='24'><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24" /><path fill='#fff' d="M21.9,21.9l-8.49-8.49l0,0L3.59,3.59l0,0L2.1,2.1L0.69,3.51L3,5.83V19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h13.17l2.31,2.31L21.9,21.9z M5,18 l3.5-4.5l2.5,3.01L12.17,15l3,3H5z M21,18.17L5.83,3H19c1.1,0,2,0.9,2,2V18.17z" /></g></svg>
```

I put them in a container like so:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
  <svg>#1 element</svg>
  <svg>#2 element</svg>
</div>
```

As, you can see, both width and height of the elements are set to `24` and yet the output on the DOM shows different dimentions:

[image]

I'm no expert when it comes to SVG and the rules about sizes relative to it's container etc..

Is there a way I can set the same size for both SVG elements and get the proper result ?

Comment: They are the same size, it's just what's drawn is different.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it in the MD docs ..

Comment: you may add a border to see that the 2 svg elements are the same size

Comment: Unfortunately you are both right .. thanks